# Unable to access variable inside listener

Tags: java, android

I have a listener excerpt below which contains the variable degree.

```
public class CustomOnItemSelectedListener implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    //Define Components
    public EditText text;
    public Spinner spinner1;
    //Define Variables
    public String degree;

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {
        //Set the selected item on spinner1 to the variable tempValue
        String tempValue = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        degree = "jobby";
    }
```

I am trying to access that variable within my ViewPager adapter like so:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public CustomOnItemSelectedListener selectedListener;

    [...]

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
        switch(pos) {

            case 0: return resultFragment.newInstance(selectedListener.degree);
            case 1: return resultFragment.newInstance("resultFragment, Instance 2");
            default: return resultFragment.newInstance("resultFragment, Default");
        }
    }

    [...]
}
```

And in my MainActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    [...]


    myPager = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    selectedListener = new CustomOnItemSelectedListener();

    addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();
    myPager.selectedListener = selectedListener;
}
```

The issue I am having is that I am unable to access the variable of degree.  If I set the value of the variable at the top of the listener class like so

```
public String degree = "jobby";
```

Then I can access the variable.

I am trying to write an if statement within the listener, and depending on which item of the spinner is selected, the variable changes.

How can I access the variable within the listener class?

Comment: what error do you got?

Comment: selectedListener should be of type CustomOnItemSelectedListener is n't it?

Comment: There is no error.  It builds and runs fine, it just doesn't output the variable content.

Comment: @Arju yes - this is defined in my main class:         selectedListener = new CustomOnItemSelectedListener();

Comment: Ok , let the string be static, and make sure that you are using te same insatnce of object to acces the string

Comment: No joy there I'm afraid.  I have a feeling it's because it's within a void, however I'm not 100% sure.  Like I say, declaring the string value at the start of the class works.

Comment: @Xeo so where is it declared and where is it initialized

Comment: Just updated the question with some more of my code..

Comment: The variable is set to "jobby" only when onItemSelected is called. Does it get called before getItem?

Comment: Not in the PageAdapter no.  However even when I call onItemSelected by selecting something from the dropdown, it still is not populated.  The idea is that the variable would change depending on what dropdown option was chosen

Comment: Are you sure that myPager.selectedListener = selectedListener; set the listener right?
You could just use Log to be sure onItemSelected is called.

Comment: Yep.  If in the adapter before the switch statement I output selectedListener.degree to the log, it outputs the value of the variable. It just doesn't work in the switch statement..

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you need initialize the variable, try this:

```
 public String degree = null;
```

And make sure when you use the variable it's with the correct value, to try avoid NullPointerExceptions.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that wouldn't matter, otherwise all variables would have to be initialised as null.  I'll give it a try though!

Comment: The other are initialized when you put a value in the variable in the same class, try use a value of the variable before set any value, you'll get an error. This is the same, the other classes aren't setting any value in the variable and it's trying to use the value of the variable.

Comment: Setting it to null still didn't return the value set later on.  Even without that, I'm not getting any NullPointerExceptions

Answer (score 0):

In CustomOnItemSelectedListener#onItemSelected the fragment needs to be replaced using the Activity's FragmentManager.

Refer to the [Fragment example code](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Example) (scroll down to the `showDetails()` method). However, instead of `FragmentManager#findFragmentById` you should use `FragmentManager#findFragmentByTag`.

Perhaps something like this:

```
    FragmentManager fragManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction xact = fragManager.beginTransaction();
    ResultFragment resultFragment = (ResultFragment)fragManager.findFragmentByTag(selectedListener.degree); 
    if(resultFragment == null) {
        mList = resultFragment.newInstance(selectedListener.degree);
        xact.add(R.id.view_container, resultFragment, selectedListener.degree);
    }
    xact.commit();
```

Be careful, though, if `degree` varies wildly then this would result in many Fragments contained in the FragmentManger. In this case you should remove the unused Fragments as needed.